# Hide android status bar for my application on Android 4.0.4?

Tags: android, statusbar

I tried with the following code to hide status bar but it doesn't work..

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

and to dim the bar i used

```
 getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

and it works.. Does any one know how to hide status bar on Android 4.0.4 device??

Comment: use the theme style...use no titlebar    <activity
            android:name="com.blank.blank.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >

Comment: No..I tried. Its not working.. ('m using Android Network Media Player 4.0 device)

Answer (score 7):

Use the following in your Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".abc"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

This however will only work on phones, Tablets do not support hiding of status bar.

Comment: Okay.. ('m using Android Network Media Player 4.0 device) .. But i downloaded a GMD HideBar 1.1.3.apk file from [Link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1769761) and installed, it works.. Actually it hides status bar but problem is sometimes device will be restarted and sometimes it won't hide bar.

Comment: THe above code should work correctly, you do however need to keep in mind you need to add the above code to each activity you have.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this on your `onCreate` method.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: This method worked for me. Its worth noting that I do have my current app restricted to landscape orientation though.

Answer (score 2):

1. add a style and extend Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar , and add two item.

like this

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style
```

2. setup your application with this theme.

like this

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    ...>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest just add it to `android:theme`. Either of the following lines should work for you:

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

You need to specify Fullscreen otherwise your status bar will be kept and only your Title bar will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

`View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` doesn't hide the status bar. It hides the navigation bar.
If you want to hide the status bar you should use:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

or

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Read more here:
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Answer (score -1):

This Solution worked with me :

1- Root your device. use the tool in this site >> www.unlockroot.com

2- call this function at application start up >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/14940667/1995361