# how to hide the status bar in launcher?

Tags: android, statusbar, launcher

there are launcher which offers the possibility to hide or protect the status bar. i tried to get the position of the menu with TouchEvent and menu position when there is a touch I put a popup to say you are not allowed but the touchEvent gives  actions on screen so how can I hide the status bar 
I tried

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_grid);
        mGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        mGrid.setColumnWidth(95);
        mGrid.setVisibility(0x00000000);
        mGrid.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800009/hide-android-status-bar-for-my-application-on-android-4-0-4

Comment: what device / emulator configuration are you trying this? btw, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178237/setsystemuivisibilitysystem-ui-flag-layout-hide-navigation-does-not-work), could be useful

Comment: @diez I know that when things don't work it can be quite frustrating (sadly I know it very well), but if you want others to help you, I suggest you to collaborate, otherwise people will very likely ignore you and your problem.

Comment: i am trying to use  setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) as mentioned in the link

Answer (score 2):

you can do it programmatically by calling

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

I think you must do it before than

```
setContentView(whatever);
```

or by editing app style, adding

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

inside `<style>`

Comment: @diez well, it would be nice if you could say what you've already tried when asking a question, and eventually post some code ^^

Comment: getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  setContentView(R.layout.main_grid);
  mGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
  mGrid.setColumnWidth(95);
  mGrid.setVisibility(0x00000000);
  mGrid.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

Comment: @diez could you please edit your question? reading code in the comment is a punch in the stomach

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this in your Manifest?

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: this one is for the title bar and not the status bar

Comment: no, i tried some launcher when we click, on it we have a message action is denied. i would like to do something like that but i don't know how.