# How to hide the Status Bar?

Tags: android

I am trying to hide the status bar. I have tried the following things.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

In the `Manifest.XML` I have added the above code.

And in the `onCreate()` I have added the following:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
// hide statusbar of Android
// could also be done later
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

But still I am unable to hide the status bar. Can anyone help?

Comment: which device you are using ? 4.0 + (Tablet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approaches you've taken would work on 2.3.X

But if you are talking about 4.0 tablets this is the code

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);    
layout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

If you're talking about a tablet you cannot get rid of the system bar but I suggest you look at this question:

[Hide Status bar on Android Ice Cream Sandwich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729464/hide-status-bar-on-android-ice-cream-sandwich)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you are writing above code lines before the line setContentView()?