# Android Edit Navigation Bar

Tags: android

i want to hide everything in Navigation bar except back button (rooted tablet) , i used to hide the Navigation bar completely (to restrict users access other applications and device settings) but the customers didn't like it because when users open PDF files or videos they forced to use physical back button to back to my application, so the only way is to customize the Navigation bar to show back button only , any suggestions?

EDIT : its possible to create my own Navigation bar like full!screen?

Comment: i guess what you need is a action bar

Comment: There is no back button in the ActionBar, it's really hard to understand what you are talking about

Comment: @Waza_Be Sorry for confusing , i'm talking about the bar where back , home and tabs buttons located

Comment: Navigation Bar ;-) see: http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html

Comment: Hello could you tell how you hide the navigation bar (rooted phone) just curious.

Comment: @Rotary Heart sorry i just saw your question , this answer helped me alot http://stackoverflow.com/a/14940667/2408440

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to do a kiosk tablet. A lightly customized rom with a navigation bar having only the back button might be what you want to do..

Comment: Yes, full!screen app on google play does that .. but i have no idea how